# Voice over gender changes between UIKit and SwiftUI views

Tags: swiftui, uikit, voiceover, uiaccessibility

My app language is set to French.

If my device language is set to French, I do not see this issue.

If my device language is set to English, In the app, voice over reads all UIKit views with female voice (French accent), and all SwiftUI view with male voice (French accent).

Is this a bug with SwiftUI or UIKit ?

I would expect the gender voice should not be changed irrespective of UIKit/SwiftUI views. I tried many ways, but none fixed the issues.

I am not sure what is causing this or how to fix this.
Our app is majorly built in UIKit and we started to use SwiftUI views for small views, and if this accessibility issues continue, we would like to stop using SwiftUI.

Some of the ways I tried are:

- Set the locale of swiftUI view, and set it as "fr-CA"

```
.environment(\.locale, "fr-CA")
.environment(\.locale, Locale(languageCode: "fr", languageRegion: .canada))
.typesettingLanguage(.init(identifier: "fr_CA"), isEnabled: true)
```

Setting the locale to "en_US" does have the same female voice on both UIKit and SwiftUI views, but it looses the French accent.

I could not find anything in the documentation that could address this.

**Note:**
The alerts shown in SwiftUI views has female French accent voice over, same as UIKit views. It is just the SwiftUI view elements are getting read with male French accent voice.

If I push the SwiftUI view using UIHostingController and UINavigationController, then the navigation bar on top of SwiftUI is read with female voice over, but when you scroll down to SwiftUI view, the voice overs gets changes to male accent.

Comment: I think that this is due to French is not exactly canadian French. (The 2 French can have different voice gender) What happens if you set no language to your app ?